# send a php variable in a function to javascript troubleshoot

Tags: php, javascript, function

i have the function get_path_dis() and i want to send the resultant to  javascript and alert result.  while opening the page the alert doesn't show. can someone tell me where am i mistaken

```
function get_path_dis($array){

//print_r($array);

$total = count($array);
$current = $array[0]['distance'];
$loop=0;

//get shortest distance
for($loop=1;$loop<$total;$loop++){

 $next = $array[($loop)]['distance'];

if ($next<$current){

    $current = $next;
    //print_r('<pre>');

    }
}

//shortest path array;
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){

    if ($current==$array[$i]['distance'])

    {
        $xmlConv = $array[$i];
    }
}

$x = json_encode($xmlConv);


?>


 function get_path_dis($array){

  //print_r($array);

$total = count($array);
$current = $array[0]['distance'];
$loop=0;

 //get shortest distance
for($loop=1;$loop<$total;$loop++){

 $next = $array[($loop)]['distance'];

if ($next<$current){

    $current = $next;
    //print_r('<pre>');

    }
}

//shortest path array;
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){

    if ($current==$array[$i]['distance'])

    {
        $xmlConv = $array[$i];
    }
}

$x = json_encode($xmlConv);


?> 



 <script type="Javascript">

 <!--
var 
$json_val= "<?php echo($x);?>";
alert($json_val);

//-->

 </script>
```

Comment: the script continues.. 
<script type="Javascript">

<!--
 var 
 $json_val= "<?php echo($x);?>";
 alert($json_val);

//-->

</script>




<?

}

?>

Comment: you gotta write more clear code, in terms of formatting. There are some standards that help readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to be encapsulated in php start and end tags.

```
alert('<?php echo json_val; ?>');
```